# how to close activity properly when back pressed

Tags: java, android

I am opening a fragment1 on Activity A and go fragment1 to Activity B and back again fragment1 when i went again fragment1 to Activity B then click on button (Activity B) then re open Activity B. but i want finish this activity B and open again Activity A if i do without back press ( Activity A -> fragment1 -> Activity B  -> onClick button ) then it work fine. 
one more thing if i back press 2 or more time then ActivityB also re-open 2 or more time. here I try with onBackPressed():

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    theatreList.clear();
    finish();
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

and there is onClick of button( Activity B)

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("bundleIds", bundleIds);
    setIntent(intent);
    finish();
```

and finish() function:

```
@Override
public void finish() {
    setResult(RESULT_OK, getIntent());
    super.finish();
}
```

Comment: I didn't get what you mean here

Comment: I have an Activity A and I am open a fragment1 and then open Activity B.

Comment: And what is your problem and want you to achieve?

Comment: Although it will be more complex, I think you can create a minimized version of your full code of ActivityA, ActivityB, Fragment1 and your android manifest that can reproduce the exact bug

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this ?

```
if ( getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 1) { finish(); } else { super.onBackPressed(); }
```